# Laravel create simple drop-down from relationship and concat columns

Tags: php, laravel

i want to create simple drop-down inside html code from 2 table which they have single relationship, in my code i cant to get relationship data to concat that with other table columns. for example this is my code:

```
$user_accounts = UserAccountNumber::with('currencyType')->select('*', DB::raw('CONCAT("CardNumber: ", card_number) AS account_info'))
            ->whereUserId(Auth::user()->id)
            ->pluck('account_info', 'id');
```

this code work fine, but i want to conact some `currencyType` table columns with `UserAccountNumber` table and i cant use tableName.columnName into `DB::raw()`

for example:

```
$user_accounts = UserAccountNumber::with('currencyType')
    ->select(
        '*', 
        DB::raw('CONCAT(" CardNumber: ", card_number, "CurrencyType: ", currencyType.title) AS account_info'))
        ->whereUserId(Auth::user()->id)
->pluck('account_info', 'id');
```

then i get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'currencyType.currency_type' in 'field list' (SQL: select *, CONCAT("AccountNumber: ",account_number, " CardNumber: ", card_number, "CurrencyType: ", currencyType.currency_type) AS account_info from `user_account_numbers` where `user_id` = 17)
```

`currencyType` method in Model:

```
public function currencyType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(CurrencyType::class, 'currency_type', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Because Laravel load relationship by 2 queries, not join. 
I think you must do `JOIN` manually or concat string in PHP

Comment: @LêTrầnTiếnTrung Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel does not use JOINs to do relationships, so you would have to write a specific query for that. Use query builder for that.

Something like this should work:

```
$user_accounts = DB::table('user_account_numbers')
    ->join('currencyType', 'user_account_numbers.currency_id', '=', 'currencyType.id')
    ->select('*', DB::raw('CONCAT(" CardNumber: ", card_number, "CurrencyType: ", currencyType.title) AS account_info'))
    ->whereUserId(Auth::user()->id)
    ->get();
```

I hope you get the idea and can adapt it to suit your database schema.

Comment: thats my default solution to use `Query Builder` instead of Eloquent, Thanks